# How to reduce cyclomatic complexity in java?

Tags: java, complexity-theory, reduce

How can I reduce the cyclomatic complexity of this function in java?:

```
public void execute() {

        if (dx == 1 && dy == 0) { this.moveRight();}
        if (dx == -1 && dy == 0) { this.moveLeft();}
        if (dx == 0 && dy == -1) { this.moveUp();}
        if (dx == 0 && dy == 1) { this.moveDown();}
        if (dx == 1 && dy == -1) { this.moveUpRight();}
        if (dx == 1 && dy == 1) { this.moveRightDown();}
        if (dx == -1 && dy == -1) { this.moveLeftUp();}
        if (dx == -1 && dy == 1) { this.moveDownLeft();}
}
```

Comment: as there are 8 methods, u need to have 8 conditions, that sorta make sense. btw, u probably want to use `if,else if` statement because, as the program is, every time all 8 conditions get executed

Comment: Is `moveUpRight()` the same as `moveUp()` + `moveRight()`  ?

Comment: we don't know what those methods do. Maybe `moveUpRight` just call `moveUp(); moveRight();`, maybe not. Without that, I can't see a way to reduce the complexity. If you ask this question because something like sonar raises a warning, sometime it's good to ignore it.

Comment: This might be a good question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java

Comment: @PieterDeBie Except this would be closed in seconds at Code Review for being hypothetical/too broad.

Comment: when you say 'cyclomatic complexity' how does this apply on your code? does eg. `moveRight()` change the values of `dx`and/or `dy`?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Ok, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

I think the following will be less complex in terms of cyclomatic complexity:

```
public void execute() {
    if (dx ==  0) {this.moveVerticaly(dy)}
    if (dx ==  1) {this.moveRight(dy)}
    if (dx == -1) {this.moveHorizontaly(dy)}
}
```

Comment: Smart.    Minor point:   The last method call could be renamed to: "moveLeft" instead of "moveHorizontaly"

Answer (score 2):

Consider transforming `dx` and `dy` to a unique value and `switch`ing on it:

`switch ((dx + 1) * 4 + (dy + 1))`

A `switch` jump is effectively constant in time, at the expense of the computation of the `switch` expression.

`case 1` corresponds to `dx == -1` and `dy == 0`, and so on.

Comment: While this may formally reduce complexity, it introduces a bewildering constant (4) and obfuscates the code. It misses the intent of reducing complexity, which is to make the code more easily understandable.